# How to specify routing using nodejs elasticsearch client?

Tags: node.js, routes, elasticsearch

There doesn't seem to be a way to specify routing value during index operation.
I attempted to use 'undocumented params' as mentioned here:
https://www.npmjs.org/package/elasticsearch

e.g.
client.search( {
  index: 'abc',
  type: 'efg',
  routing: '123'
  .
  .
  .
}

I would get 'routing' error since routing is required in the mapping. 
Is this a bug, missing feature, or am I not setting the correct parameters?  Please help

Answer (score 4):

A little late, but for anyone wondering you can set the routing in the connection path:

```
var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
  host: 'http://u:pwd@host:port?routing={routing_key}'
});

{ total: 1, successful: 1, failed: 0 }
```

Also, you can add it as a parameter in the search object:

```
.search( { index: 'indexname',
  type: 'typename',
  body: { query: { bool: [Object] }, size: 1, aggs: { agg1: [Object] } },
  routing: '2015-03,2015-04' })
```